# Query about How to display arrow on road in two ways if road is twoway

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am a beginner with GeoServer, i built a code for road mapping and it work but now i want to display arrow on road according to road direction in both way if road is bidirectional,then arrow should display in both way.....

I have tried following code but it display the arrow only at center.....
please reply me for both direction....

```
    <Rule>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>FUNC_CLASS</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
          <ogc:Literal>;</ogc:Literal>
        </Label>
        <Font>
          <CssParameter name="font-family">Lucida Sans</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-size">15</CssParameter>              
        </Font>

        <LabelPlacement>
        <LinePlacement>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-5</PerpendicularOffset>

        </LinePlacement>
        </LabelPlacement>

        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#585858</CssParameter>
        </Fill>

        <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="forceLeftToRight">false</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="forceRightToLeft">true</VendorOption>

      </TextSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
     </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Comment: what determines if a road is one or two way?